# How to add EditForm for editing row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I add edit form row in Asp.NET `GridView` control like [this RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx)!

When I click on the Edit button, I want to add an edit form row under the edit button row.

Here my Grid

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPersonnel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    //..
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    //..
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    //..
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle></EditRowStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your GridView attributes add AutoGenerateEditButton and a custom event handler for OnRowEditing like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowEditing="gvEG_RowEditing">
```

Then in your code-behind make a new event handler method called "gvEG_RowEditing". Have your method add a panel under the row that is being edited. Add the necessary fields to the panel as well as an update button. Create a click event handler for the update button and have it save all the fields to the database and then rebind the GridView.

Comment: This is the bare minimum you will need. You should probably also add a row canceling edit handler as well as some other things, but this should get you started.